# UFW - how to know which ports are blocked by default?

Tags: debian, security, ufw

Regarding using UFW ("Uncomplicated Fire Wall") how could one know which ports are blocked by default, that is right after doing `apt-get install ufw -y && ufw enable`?

Don't have a machine to test it right now, maybe `ufw status verbose` I've seen in the [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) show these as well?

Comment: `iptables -L -n -v` ?

Comment: I got about 170 lines of output there. What's needed from there?

Comment: see my answer below for more info. Sounds like you might have had some firewall rules already in place.

Comment: Oh yes I use CSF-LFD in this particular environment and doesn't have one to test. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pretty much answered your own question:

> Don't have a machine to test it right now, maybe `ufw status verbose`?

**Yes**. Here is an example from a server I own:

```
ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

As you can see, the default for `ufw` is to deny ALL incoming traffic. 
You then need to specify which ports should be allowed, and you can of course fine tune these rules to only allow from certain addresses and/or subnets etcetera.

See `man ufw` or follow **[this link](http://man.he.net/man8/ufw)** for a bunch of good examples.

Answer (score 2):

> how could one know which ports are blocked by default, that is right after doing `apt-get install ufw -y && ufw enable`?

By default, Debian doesn't have any rules, and has a policy of ALLOW, in the default ("filter") table. So, assuming nothing besides `ufw` has been in a position to override Debian's defaults, then immediately after running your commands above, you could run `iptables -L -n -v`.

This will verbosely (`-v`) list all the rules in the default ("filter") table (`-L`), without performing time-consuming and unnecessary reverse DNS lookups (`-n`). Anything different to the default setup must have been put there by `ufw`.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy when you use the graphical interface for managing UFW.

```
apt-get install gufw
```

Works smoothly for me.